# Regex to replace excel formula with sheet name

Tags: javascript, regex, js-xlsx

Hi i am trying to write a regex to replace occurrence of cell name in an excel formulae with a alias in place of sheet name. I am using Js XLS for parsing excel.
ex :

```
 +AA74/AVERAGE('b'!Z40:AA40)
```

Output Required

```
 +a_AA74/AVERAGE(b_Z40:b_AA40)
```

current Output

```
 +a_AA74/AVERAGE(b_Z40:a_AA40)
```

where 'a' is the current sheet in which formulae is written and 'b' is the name of other sheet.I want to append sheet name before each cell name.
But in this type of formula range formula should contain starting range sheet name.

Current Code I am using

```
var re = new RegExp("A.","g");
res = res.replace(re, "a_");
var re = new RegExp("A!","g");
res = res.replace(re, "a_");
var re = new RegExp("'B'!","g");
res = res.replace(re, "b_");
var re = new RegExp("'B'.","g");
res = res.replace(re, "b_");
res = res.replace(/\s/g,"");
res = res.replace(/(^|[^_A-Z])([A-Z]+\d+)/g, "$1"+'a_'+"$2");
```

Comment: Please check https://jsfiddle.net/33bxwc2c/ and let me know if this works for you.

Comment: thanks it is what am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```js
var re = /^\+A!?|'b'!([A-Z]+\d+):([A-Z]+\d+)/g;
var s = "+AA74/AVERAGE('b'!Z40:AA40)";
var res = s.replace(re, function(m, g1, g2) {
  if (g1) {
   return 'b_'+g1 + ":b_" + g2;
  } else return '+a_A';
});
console.log(res);
```

The `^\+A!?|'b'!([A-Z]+\d+):([A-Z]+\d+)` regex matches:

- `^\+A!?` - `+A` or `+A!` at the start of the string
- `|`  -  or
- `'b'!`  - a sequence of literal chars
- `([A-Z]+\d+)`  - Group 1 capturing 1+ uppercase ASCII chars followed with 1+ digits
- `:` - a colon
- `([A-Z]+\d+)` - Group 2 capturing 1+ uppercase ASCII chars followed with 1+ digits

In the replacement, we check if the Group 1 matched (=participated in the match). If yes, we add `b_` to the captured contents, if not, we just add `a_` to `A`.